# Can not reinitialize select2 inside any function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying add `select2` programmatically. here is the my code

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnAddRow", function(e) {
  var newText = $(".rawRow").html();
  var lastText = '<div class="row productInfoRow" style="margin-top: 5px;">' + newText + '</div>';
  $(".productInfoRow:last").after(lastText);
  $(".productList:last").focus();

  $(".productList").select2("destroy").select2();  
});
```

But i am getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selec2 is not a function` error.

The first select which i have initialized outside function is working.

```
<script>
   $(".productList").select2();
</script>
```

But it's not working otherwise.

[image]

As you can see in the picture 1st one working. but second or third ones not working.

Comment: So you mean want to run `select2` for example after click?

Comment: Yes exactly, after click, or after ajax success event or etc. but i couldnt make it run.

Comment: You don't need to `destroy` or `reinitialize` just call it when you want.

Comment: Are you sure that select2("destroy") returns jq element? Try to call destroy and reinit separatelly..

Comment: Can you please ensure that the code that you pasted here and the code that you are running are the same.
The error message you posted here shows `selec2` is not a function, which is not really a function. You missed a `t` in your spelling.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple call after click:**

You can call `select2` after click function so easily:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnAddRow", function(e) {
  //var newText = $(".rawRow").html();
  //var lastText = '<div class="row productInfoRow" style="margin-top: 5px;">' + newText + '</div>';
  // $(".productInfoRow:last").after(lastText);
  //$(".productList:last").focus();

  $('.productList').select2();

});
```

```css
#btnAddRow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select class="productList" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="btnAddRow">Add Select2</div>
```

**With dynamically data:**

Or you can append new data to it, without initialize or destroy. or even `ajax call` it will automatically add data.

```js
$('.productList').select2();

$(document).on("click", "#btnAddRow", function(e) {
  //var newText = $(".rawRow").html();
  //var lastText = '<div class="row productInfoRow" style="margin-top: 5px;">' + newText + '</div>';
  // $(".productInfoRow:last").after(lastText);
  //$(".productList:last").focus();

  $('.productList').append('<option value="US">United State</option>');
  

});
```

```css
#btnAddRow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select class="productList" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="btnAddRow">Add Some other option</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that when i call it after click event i get error  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function.

Comment: You see, it works here without any error, so check you application, maybe there is conflict or rendering order issue or included library twice. Which version are you using? try to use my version in this snippet @maxileft